# Gource command error while loading shared libraries: ?: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Tags: git, gource

I am new to using Git (I know the basics) and Gource
I am using Git for repository, but I can't find much information about the install, however I managed to do most of it before using the command line (at which point I couldn't use because the video was on Slik SVN). Gource is installed in the default path for Windows (64-bit, Windows 10).
Every time I use Git Bash MinGW64 with any of the Gource commands it says 
    C:/Gource/gource.exe: error while loading shared libraries: ?: cannot open
    shared object file: No such file or directory
Sorry if this is already posted, I couldn't find it anywhere
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

If you have strace, you can do it:

```
$ strace file
file.exe - System Error
---------------------------
The program can't start because cygz.dll is missing from your computer. Try
reinstalling the program to fix this problem.
```

Comment: I don't think I have it, it might work on Cygwin, but I don't expect I can run both terminals co-operatively